# Why is Ebean ORM throwing java.sql.SQLException: IJ031021: You cannot rollback during a managed transaction

Tags: jdbc, jax-rs, ebean

I have a Jax-RS Rest service that uses Ebean to query the database. On any query I make this exception is thrown.

For example.

```
User currentUser = new QUser().where().id.eq(currentUserID)).findUnique();
```

Logs

> ERROR [io.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction] (default task-10) Error when ending a query only transaction via ROLLBACK: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031021: You cannot rollback during a managed transaction

Now the query returns the appropriate user and doesn't interfere with the Jax-RS.

But I can't ignore the large code-smell

And the huge log that is created because it gets thrown on every query.

## My Configuration

```
ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
        config.setDataSource(ds);
        config.setName("db");
        config.setAutoCommitMode(false);
        config.setDatabasePlatform(new PostgresPlatform());
        config.setRegister(true);
        config.setDefaultServer(true);
        config.setTransactionRollbackOnChecked(true);
        config.addPackage(User.class.getPackage().getName());
        EbeanServer es = EbeanServerFactory.create(config);
```

Comment: How is your connection set up?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I added my configuration for Ebean.

Comment: The error suggests you are using managed transactions and something other than the transaction manager is trying to rollback (probably Ebean). What is your data source config, are you using a transaction manager (eg something like Spring `@Transactional`)? You may need to set auto-commit mode to `true`, or use a module like ebean-spring-txn. Note I don't know ebean, just guessing based on some parts of the documentation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Setting autoCommit did the trick but I want to investigate the source of this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ebean inside Java EE you need to configure the EbeanServer before it is used. A typical place to do it is in a @PostConstruct method in a @Startup @Singleton bean-managed transaction ejb. And you need to configure it to use the JTA transaction manager so it doesn't try to begin/commit the transactions on its own.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class AtStartup {

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/datasources/EbeanTestDS")
    private DataSource ds;

    @SneakyThrows
    @PostConstruct
    public void startup() {
        new MigrationRunner(new MigrationConfig()).run(ds); // begin/commits transaction for the migration...

        ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
        config.setDataSource(ds);
        config.addPackage(Customer.class.getPackage().getName());
        config.setUseJtaTransactionManager(true); // This is important !
        config.setAutoCommitMode(false);
        EbeanServerFactory.create(config);
    }
```